# Is iOS 64-bit simulator really 64-bit?

Tags: ios, objective-c

According to [Major 64-Bit Changes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaTouch64BitGuide/Major64-BitChanges/Major64-BitChanges.html)
int & long sizes are 4 and 8 bytes. But when I run on iOS 64-bit simulator with following code:

```
NSLog(@"NSInteger size: %i", sizeof(NSInteger));
NSLog(@"int       size: %i", sizeof(int));
NSLog(@"long      size: %i", sizeof(long));
```

The output is

> ```
>  NSInteger size: 4
>  int       size: 4
>  long      size: 4
> ```

So, the sizes tell us another. What's output on real device?

Comment: Why dont you try it on a real device?

Comment: @NikosM. iPhone 5S (the first x64 iOS device) is fairly new. Not everyone can afford to go out and buy one off contract.

Comment: @vcsjones totally agree, but it is not the only 64-bit iOS device right now.

Comment: @NikosM. Perhaps because the question is about the Simulator, and not the real device...

Comment: @NikosM: There is also the iPad mini and iPad Air, which are at least $399. Not everyone can afford to go out and buy one of those either.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, the simulator is 64-bit. You get this output because probably your app is not compiled for 64-bit. In your project settings select the following (including 64-bit)

[image]